# Using Facebook API in PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I am currently learning PHP and I want to start incorporating Facebook basic elements such as friend lists etc just to do something more fun than building a web shop. However, I have followed the guides on Facebook and added an app and I got the canvas to display what I want, but how do I start getting data from Facebook? I have downloaded this https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk#readme and I added it to my project.

For example, how would I ask for permissions, pull data from my own profile? Do I need to parse JSON? Where is the API for the PHP SDK? This http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ does not look like the get user id part here:

```
require 'php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Any points in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960376/incorporating-facebook-login-using-facebook-php-sdk-v-3-0-0-with-sessions-and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to parse JSON, you would have to go about doing an API request:

```
try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $fbException) {
    die('Houston, we got problems.');
    return;
}
```

This would leave you with either a $user_profile containing every single element you've previously requested permission for (such as first_name, etc), put into an associative array (`$user_profile` in this case).
Obviously, you would first have to check for `getUser()`'s success or failure (if it returns 0, it failed), as the API call would behave as if you were logged out otherwise.

Comment: At this link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ if you look at the first example: Would "name", "type", "website"... be keys in the associative array?

Comment: Well, yes, but that would mean you are requesting a page. For actual user information (such as the example provided) you would get something like this: https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor (please notice that the information would differ if you were logged in through the API or such)

Comment: Okey, but where does it say that it returns a associative array? Which API are you looking at? How should I know?

Comment: If you're referring to the top of the page, that's JSON output representing a Facebook graph object. The current SDK can transpose this into a PHP associative array ([key] => value). `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me')` will get you a user profile, `$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends')` will get you the friend list and you can refer to the comments in my answer on how to add permissions.

Comment: Btw, Julian is right about it being preferable to use the most recent SDK. Use the graph API where you can. It's quite simple to use once you've understood how you can access properties and linked objects using paths. [Thinkdiff.net](http://thinkdiff.net/) has some nice demonstration code on how to do stuff like update status messages.

Comment: @Jolly: I know because I've seen the API examples. For more information: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tree/master/examples . Also, please notice that theres a new SDK out: v3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at example.php included with the PHP SDK? It shows how to do a login and get some basic data using the graph API. To make the permissions dialog appear in your application and retrieve an access token for a given user you can do something like this:

```
$app_id = "...";
$app_secret = "...";
$my_url = "...";

//session_start();

@$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if( empty( $code ) ){
    $dialog_url =
            "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
           . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
           . $_SESSION['state']
           . "&scope=email,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_interests,user_location,user_online_presence,user_photos,user_status,publish_stream"; // Scope defines permissions

    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>"); // Redirect
}

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

$response = file_get_contents($token_url);
$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);

$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $params['access_token'];

$testuser = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

if( $testuser != null ){
    // Do stuff
```

Comment: This example is completely unproductive. The PHP SDK 3.0.1 provides a much better way through the use of getLoginUrl() and getLogoutUrl(). The official way is also safer as it implements the use of CSRF tokens.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that this code is kind of outdated. Hence the reference to the example provided with the most recent SDK. It does demonstrate how to get a permissions dialog up and access properties. If you know how a solution to trigger `getLoginUrl()` automatically in the context of a facebook application it would be most welcome.

Comment: This would the equivalent code for bringing up permissions using getLoginUrl:  
`$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_interests,user_location,user_online_presence,user_photos,user_status,publish_stream'));`